# 00:00 slide transition in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, animation

In a Powerpoint presentation, one can choose the slide transition time: the time that a slide is visible before it automatically switches to the next slide.  The default slide transition time is 00:00

[image]

If you set a slide's transition time to 00:00, it doesn't actually skip the slide, but it shows it for a *veeeery* short time - let's call this time *t* - and then goes to the next slide.  If there are a large number of slides in the show, and they all have slide transition time set to 00:00, the whole show can last for an appreciable length of time.  *t* may be very small, but *1000t* can be several minutes.

What's this good for?  Animation!  Powerpoint's built-in animations are very good, but if you want more flexibility, nothing can beat a bit of good ol' stop-motion.

And this brings me to my problem.  A *long* time ago, I made a short animated film in Powerpoint 2000.  As I recall, it was exactly 1000 slides long.  The thing is, the value *t<sub>2000</sub>* that a 00:00 slide lasted for in Powerpoint 2000 is a lot more than the value *t<sub>2003</sub>* that it lasts for in Powerpoint 2003 (and later versions).

On my current version (Powerpoint 2003 running in Windows 8.1), a 1000-slide-long presentation where every slide is set to 00:00 lasts for around 17 seconds.  I haven't got other versions to hand, so I can't give any other figures, but they were a lot longer.  If I try to watch my old animations, they go *way* too fast!

Is there any hack I can use to manually change the actual time that a 00:00 slide lasts?  Failing that, is there another way?  A VBA trick?  Deliberately slowing down my computer?

Comment: Is that not down to a newer PC? I suspect a timing of 0 will simply go as fast as PP can load it & this will depend on CPU and memory as well as the improved efficiencies of both Windows and Office. Far better to record the presentation to video and then adjust that.

Comment: @JulianKnight I suspected that that was the case, but I wanted to see if anyone knew the inner workings of Office well enough to say for sure whether there's a built in delay for timing 0 or not.

Comment: Well I don't believe it would make any sense to have such a thing and even if it did, you wouldn't be given access to something so low-level. Honestly, recording to an actual video file and adjusting the speed is going to be a lot easier!

Comment: I realize there are good answers already, but a bad option would be to insert several duplicates of each slide so that it takes longer to run through the deck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see reasons to do a movie and reasons not to.  If you want to try the latter and adjust the timing for all of the slides, this'll do it.  Change the 5.55 to however many seconds.fractions you like:

```
Sub SetAdvanceTimeAllSlides()
    With ActivePresentation.Slides.Range
        .SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime = 5.55
    End With
End Sub
```

If nothing else, you can use this to adjust the transition times until you have it running the way you want it *on your computer*, then make a video.  You may have to adjust things again after testing that, because the act of making a video may also change the timings.

Comment: Thanks!  The only problem I had with the video idea was that some of the slides had transitions set to more than 00.00 seconds.  Nothing that couldn't be fixed, but this example looks easier to adapt to get everything working the way I want to.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (not as quick as the accepted answer, but more elementary):

It's actually possible to set the transition time to a fractional value, just by typing it in:

[image: Automatically after dialogue says: 00:00.1]

I'd somehow assumed that, since the default value in the box was

```
00:00
```

rather than

```
00:00.0
```

that this would just correct to 00:00, but it doesn't, and the presentation ends up running slightly slower than it does at 00:00.

A time of 00:00.1 works well for my old animations.  Steve's VBA script can be adapted to change the transition time to 00:00.1 on all slides that had it set to 00:00 originally.

Comment: It sounds like you've worked this out already, but if not shout:  it wouldn't be hard to adapt the macro to modify only slides with a transition time of zero or within a certain range and leave others alone.